# Wrap groupId value in maven dependency specification

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I am trying to add log4j-rolling-appender library as a dependency in my application. The jar is available here:

> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.org.simonsite/log4j-rolling-appender/

I have added the following 2 things( repository and jar specification) in pom.xml. snippet below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        ...
        ...
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>log4j-appender</id>
                <name> Repository for log4j-rolling-appender</name>
                <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.org.simonsite</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-rolling-appender</artifactId>
            <version>20131024-2017</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
        ...
</project>
```

Upon building, maven generates the following URL to download the dependency which is incorrect( Though as per the standards, it is correct however incorrect in my case):

> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk/org/simonsite/log4j-rolling-appender/20131024-2017/log4j-rolling-appender-20131024-2017.pom

*Notice how the package mentioned in groupId(uk.org.simonsite) is converted to package hierarchy in the URL (../uk/org/simonsite/).*

The URL where the JAR can be found and i want maven to generate is:

> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.org.simonsite/log4j-rolling-appender/20131024-2017/log4j-rolling-appender-20131024-2017.pom

Can someone provide any suggestion on how do i instruct maven to skip this conversion while generating the URL ?

Comment: It seems you can find it on this repository: http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/uk/org/simonsite/log4j-rolling-appender/

Comment: @Thilo Thanks. However i want maven to generate this URL and take care of dependency download. I can change the repository location however the question remains the same.

Comment: @Thilo to add more ... the repository in your comment will definitely solve my current problem. However i still would like to know answer to the actual question i asked.

Comment: I think the URL that Maven generates is "correct". The one you say you want yields a 404 Not Found https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.org.simonsite/log4j-rolling-appender/20131024-2017/log4j-rolling-appender-20131024-2017.pom  mvnrepository.com does not provide downloads I think, it is just a search portal.

Comment: Also, maybe there is an alternative library you could use? The RollingFileAppender that comes with log4j is not good?

Comment: @Thilo may be you are correct. There is no point being curious about knowing the useless hacks. Thanks for your opinion. I will use the repo URL you provided and will continue my work however will keep this question open for sometime.

Answer (score 1):

Maven repositories have a fixed format for resolving Maven coordinates.

After the starting URL, there is the groupId with `/` instead of `.`, then the artifactId, then the version, and then a filename that contains artifactId, version, classifier if present and the extension.

If you want to draw a jar from a different URL, then this URL is not a Maven repository. You should download the jar first and install it into your company repository (or your own local repository, if nothing else is available).

Answer (score -1):

If you have using multiple dependencies then you should try using  annotation wrapping all dependencies.

Also follow the pattern :

```
<project>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-a</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <type>bar</type>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-internal-site</id>
      <url>http://myserver/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

Dependencies with the scope system are always available and are not looked up in repository. Always use dependencies first before repository in order.